# MPPT current limitation

Tags: stm32, battery-charging, buck, solar-cell, mppt

I started to work on an MPPT project a couple of months ago. I have the first HW prototype (synchronous buck converter, current/voltage measurement, STM32 uC) and I am still fiddling with the SW side. The target is to charge a 12V Li-Ion battery from a couple of small 10W/50W solar panels.
Since I am a HW guy, the target of this project is to also learn to write good quality SW, and here I would need some help.

For the overcurrent protection, I will implement it in HW and make sure that the MOSFET driver gets disabled and the MOSFETs are turned off if an overcurrent situation occurs.
Now, for the bulk charging of the battery, I need a good implementation of the current limitation. The structure of the code is to check the battery state and if the battery is discharged, start the Bulk charging mode with the MPPT algorithm. If the panels are capable of delivering more than the current I am looking to charge/cell, I need a SW implementation to limit this.
Right now, I am testing the classic (if current > limit, DutyCycle--), but I feel this is kind of rough.
Can you guys give me some advices towards some better implementations of this feature? Also, voltage limitation needs to be implemented as well at the end of charging.

Comment: _”(if current > limit, DutyCycle--)”_ That would be my initial attempt too. I’ve seen OCP being interrupt driven when MCUs are used for PWM.

Comment: What is limiting the rate that you do the comparison? Every cycle? 10ms? What happens when you drop the duty cycle, the current drops, so you increase the duty cycle? Maybe you want some hysteresis?

Comment: @winny I was thinking this was too rough and there is a better way. Actually, I tested it and it seems fine, but I still have to check it closely on an oscilloscope.

Comment: @Kartman I think I have to check, but if I recall correctly, I am reading the current and updating the duty cycle every 10ms. When the duty cycle gets reduced, the current is reduced and after 10ms the power gets calculated again and the duty cycle gets increased. Basically, I would have a 10ms gap where the current might be over the expected limit.